# How to insert missing rows in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with the following columns (checkdate datetime, duration int). I have this stored procedure which groups the data per hour.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[last_hours]
    @hours int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CAST(checkdate  as date) AS ForDate,
        DATEPART(hour, checkdate ) AS OnHour,
        AVG(duration) AS Duration
    FROM 
        pings
    WHERE 
        DATEDIFF(hour, checkdate , GETDATE()) <= @hours
    GROUP BY 
        CAST(checkdate as date),
        DATEPART(hour, checkdate )
END
```

The proc works fine. However I have situations where data for certain hours is not available. In this case I need to add an extra "empty" row for every missing hour before returning the result to the client.

Is it possible to do this in an easy way without resorting to cursors and loops?

Comment: Some like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86486/results-for-every-hour-of-the-day-even-data-if-not-present)?

Comment: It would help is you show us some sample data and expected outcome, and your table schema

Comment: If you have a tally table, use it to generate list of date / hour and then left join to your table. You may also use recursive cte to generate it

Comment: @DaleK Somewhat working. I get 48 rows instead of the number or hours I need (for example 24) because I have values for 2 days. If I pass 12 I get 24 rows which are for the current day. I need the rows for the current hour  up to x previous hours.

Comment: why not using TVFs?

Answer (score 1):

this uses recursive cte to generate a list of `checkdate` and then `LEFT JOIN` to the table.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[last_hours]
    @hours int
AS
BEGIN
    WITH hours as
    (
        SELECT checkdate = DATEADD(hour, -@hours, GETDATE())
        UNION ALL
        SELECT checkdate = DATEADD(hour, 1, checkdate)
        FROM   hours
        WHERE  checkdate < GETDATE()
    )
    SELECT 
        CAST(h.checkdate  as date) AS ForDate,
        DATEPART(hour, h.checkdate ) AS OnHour,
        AVG(p.duration) AS Duration
    FROM 
        hours h
        LEFT JOIN pings p    ON CAST(h.checkdate as date)   = CAST(p.checkdate as date)
                            AND DATEPART(hour, h.checkdate) = DATEPART(hour, p.checkdate)
    GROUP BY 
        CAST(h.checkdate as date),
        DATEPART(hour, h.checkdate )
   ORDER BY ForDate, OnHour
END
```